# How to pass props from one component to another along with props validation - React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-props

Hi I am learning props validation. I am having two functions **APP** and **Person**. From the Person function I am passing variables to the APP. The variables are(Name, preferredCities, Age). I need to apply validations as follows

1. Name: Should be a string
2. Prefered Cities: Array type
3. Age: Should be number and should be greater than 18 and less than 60
   for above passed variables.

While executing this app if validation fails I need to pass default values(Name:"Steve", preferredCities:['Chennai','BLR'],Age:18). I wrote the logic for the above problem but when I am trying to render the output based on the condition using ternary operation my logic is not working. Any one can guide me where I am making mistake. Thanks in advance.

```
const Person = (props) => {
  return (
    <ul>
      <li>
        {props.strName === props.strName ? (
          props.strName
        ) : (
          <p>{Person.defaultProps.Name}</p>
        )}
      </li>
      <li>{props.num}</li>
      <li> {props.arr}</li>
    </ul>
  );
};

Person.propTypes = {
  strName: PropTypes.string,
  num: PropTypes.number,
  arr: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
};

Person.defaultProps = {
  Name: "Steve",
  preferredCities: ["Chennai", "Bangalore"],
  age: 18,
};
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Person strName={18} num={18} arr={["A", "B"]} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change one of the props.strName to propsTypes.strName.
try this `{props.strName === propTypes.strName ? (` .. remaining codes

And I think this is a better way to pass props.

```
function App() {
     const strName ="john";
     const num = 18;
     const arr =["A","B"];
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Person strName={strName} num={num} arr={arr} />
    </div>
  );
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this man :

```
const Person = ({ strName, num, arr }) => {
  return (
    <ul>
      <li>
        { strName && typeof strName === "string" ? (
          strName
        ) : (
          <p>{Person.defaultProps.Name}</p>
        )}
      </li>
      <li>{num}</li>
      <li> {arr}</li>
    </ul>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
const Person = ({ strName, num, arr }) => {
  return (
  <div>
        { strName && typeof strName === "string" ? (
          strName
        ) : (
          <p>{Person.defaultProps.Name}</p>
        )}
    </div>
   
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Default props are not for being taken when prop validation fails. Default props are fallback values when the prop is not passed when it is called in its parent component.

The string and the array validation are normal validations for your use case

For the number, you can have some custom validations:

```
const isCustomNumber = (props, propName, componentName) => {
const regexPattern = /\b(19|[2-5][0-9])\b/;
if (!regex.test(props[propName])) {
return new Error(
  `Invalid prop ${propName} passed to ${componentName}. Expected a number between 18 and 60.`
);
}
};
```

Then you could have your validation like:

```
Person.propTypes = {
strName: PropTypes.string,
num: PropTypes.isCustomNumber,
arr: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
};
```

However, this does not take the default values specified if the validation fails. This is just a type checker at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's a spelling mistake of starName should be `strName` in the person component.

```
const Person = (props) => {
  if(typeof props.starName !== 'string' || !Array.isArray(props.arr) || typeof props.num !== 'number' || props.num < 18 || props.num > 60 ) return;

  return (
  <ul>
    <li>
      {props.strName === props.strName ? (
        props.strName
      ) : (
        <p>{Person.defaultProps.Name}</p>
      )}
    </li>
    <li>{props.num}</li>
    <li> {props.arr}</li>
  </ul>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can validate your props into the Person component. Just check the props value and conditionally use the value. If you want please try the below-given code.

```
const Person = ({ strName, num, arr }) => {


const defaultValue = {
    name: "Steve",
    preferredCities: ["Chennai", "Bangalore"],
    age: 18
  };
  return (
    <ul>
      <li>{typeof strName === "string" ? strName : defaultValue.name}</li>
      <li>
        {typeof num === "number" && num > 18 && num < 60
          ? num
          : defaultValue.age}
      </li>
      <li> {Array.isArray(arr) ? arr : defaultValue.preferredCities}</li>
    </ul>
  );
};

export default Person;
```